# Comparing int's in java

Tags: java, if-statement, int

I have this script to simulate 2 die rolls in java. This is done twice, once by user and once by computer(both automatically). The program outputs the rolls and sums them up. I however cannot get an if/else statement to work to compare the rolls and determine the winner/ or tie. So far I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
/*
Program to simulate die roll
*/
public class Dice
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
Random generator= new Random();
int roll1;
int roll2;
int roll3;
int roll4;
int addroll1;
int addroll2;

public void userdieroll() // Simulates users role
{
    roll1 = (generator.nextInt(7) +1); // Generate number from 1-6
    System.out.println("Your first roll is "+roll1+"");// Says users first role
    roll2 = (generator.nextInt(7) +1); // Generate number from 1-6
    System.out.println("Your second roll is "+roll2+"");// Says users second roll
    addroll1=  roll1 +roll2;// Sums users roles
    System.out.println("The sum of your two roles is "+addroll1+" \n");
}
public void compdieroll()// Simulates computers role
{
    roll3 = (generator.nextInt(7) +1); // Generate number from 1-6
    System.out.println("The computers first role is "+roll3+""); // Says computers first role
    roll4 = (generator.nextInt(7) +1); // Generate number from 1-6
    System.out.println("The computers second role is "+roll4+""); // Says computers second role
    addroll2=  roll3 +roll4;// Sums computers roles
    System.out.println("The sum of the computers roles is "+addroll2+""); 
}
public void findwinner()
{
        if (addroll1 == addroll2)
        {
            System.out.println("Its a tie!");
        }
        else
        {   
           if (addroll1 > addroll2)
           {
               System.out.println("You Won!");
           }

           else
           {
               System.out.println("You lost!");
           }

}
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Dice userroll = new Dice();
    userroll.userdieroll();
    Dice comproll = new Dice();
    comproll.compdieroll();
    Dice looper = new Dice();
    looper.findwinner();

}

}
```

Comment: `roll1 = (generator.nextInt(7) +1); // Generate number from 1-6`, um, no. Generate a number from 0 to 6, then add one, will get you numbers 1 to 7 (inclusive).

Comment: Yea oops my bad nice catch

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new `Dice` object each time you call a method. When you do this, you are not storing `addroll1` and `addroll2` in the same object, so it is only natural that `.findwinner()` doesn't work as expected in your third object, where you have not stored any values in `addroll1` and `addroll2`. To fix this, use the same `Dice` object for all three methods, like so:

```
Dice tester = new Dice();
tester.userdieroll();
tester.compdieroll();
tester.findwinner();
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that! It makes sense when you think about it!

Answer (score 1):

Mmmh, from a first look you are instantiating three different objects. And `findwinner()` is working on `addroll1 = 0` and `addroll2 = 0` since `0` is the default value for this class property.

If you want to work on the same data from different objects, you need to make properties `static`.
Anyways, as other suggested, do the job on a single instance.

Comment: Making the properties `static` is a terrible approach. One should not hold mutable static state; that gives you all the pain of global variables, such as lack of testability or scalability, and loss of control over object lifecycle. @UnknowableIneffible [sic] has the better solution.

Comment: I know. As I stated the best approach is to use a single instance with its properties. But the OP used three differents objects, so static is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I suggest that the answer that didn't suggest the "static mutable state" antipattern is acceptable, not ones that do suggest that antipattern.

Comment: You can consider acceptable UnknowableIneffible answer, that's fine. I'll repeat, I just told the OP how Java works.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an idea how I would have implemented it (with about 20 years of experience programming Java):

```
package nl.owlstead.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Random;

/*
 * Program to simulate a double die roll.
 */
public class DiceGame {
    private Random generator = new Random();

    enum Result {
        LOSER,
        TIE,
        WINNER;
    }

    public DiceGame() {
        // nothing to do in constructor
    }

    public int rollDice() {
        int zeroToFive = generator.nextInt(6);
        int oneToSix = zeroToFive + 1;
        return oneToSix;
    }

    public Result findWinner(int totalRollComp, int totalRollUser) {
        if (totalRollComp > totalRollUser) {
            return Result.LOSER;
        }

        if (totalRollComp < totalRollUser) {
            return Result.WINNER;
        }

        return Result.TIE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DiceGame game = new DiceGame();
        int firstRollComp = game.rollDice();
        int secondRollComp = game.rollDice();
        int totalRollComp = firstRollComp + secondRollComp;
        System.out.printf("Comp rolled: %d and %d, totalling %d%n", firstRollComp, secondRollComp,
                totalRollComp);

        int firstRollUser = game.rollDice();
        int secondRollUser = game.rollDice();
        int totalRollUser = firstRollUser + secondRollUser;
        System.out.printf("User rolled: %d and %d, totalling %d%n", firstRollUser, secondRollUser,
                totalRollUser);

        Result userResult = game.findWinner(totalRollComp, totalRollUser);
        switch (userResult) {
        case LOSER:
            System.out.println("You lost!");
            break;
        case TIE:
            System.out.println("Its a tie!");
            break;
        case WINNER:
            System.out.println("You Won!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What is especially useful is to use as few fields as possible. As you already found out using fields (which represents *state* in a program) is pretty dangerous. If you can avoid state, you should do so. So in this program there is just one field: the random number generator (of course I would use `new SecureRandom()` instead).

Furthermore it also shows the strength of choosing good names for your variables and splitting output (`System.out`) and the game itself. I've tried not to introduce too many techniques beside that, but I could not resist using an enum for the result and `printf` to simplify the various `println` statements.

Comment: Excellent answer that illustrates several best practices. Doing nothing in a constructor besides initialization is one that is far too commonly violated.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one object, you are creating 3 dices and those values are not statically shared between instances...

This will work:

```
Dice userroll = new Dice();
userroll.userdieroll();
userroll.compdieroll();
userroll.findwinner();
```

Answer (score -1):

In your class there are both the user dice than the computer dice variables.
in your main you should create only one class:

```
Dice d = new Dice();
d.userdieroll();
d.compdieroll();
d.findwinner();
```

your code creates three different instances of Dice with three different `roll1`, `roll2`, ... when you write

```
...
Dice looper = new Dice();
looper.findwinner();
```

it compares varlable `looper.addroll1` with `looper.addroll2` (i.e. the ones inside the looper class), but these variables are still 0 (default value), in the lines before you populated `userroll.addroll1` and `comproll.addroll2`.

Vjncenzo

Comment: It is false that the OP's code "creates three different classes" and also false that the `addroll1` "variables were not initialized".